# How to apply color to faces of scanned object

Tags: texturing

I have a scanned model created using 3DF Zephyr.  As you can see in the image, there are some areas that the camera didn't reach, which Zephyr filled in grey.  There are also a lot of black shadows.  I want to change the grey areas to black so that they just look like more shadows.

I'm a blender newbie, and all the information I've found online is way over my head.

I've figured out to switch to Texture Paint mode.  I'd like to just edit the existing texture to put black in the desired places.  The model is small enough to just do it manually.  I've figured out how to draw black onto the texture and see it appear on the model.

My problem is finding the right part of the texture image to draw black on.  I can select faces in the 3D window, and I think that the corresponding part of the 2D texture image gets highlighted, but I don't know for sure because the faces are too small to find the highlighted parts in the image.  What I'd like to be able to do is select a face on the 3D model, then zoom the 2D image to that face and manually add black to it.  But I can't find a way to zoom to the selected face.

Alternatively, it seems like I should be able to set a "paint mask" consisting of the grey faces, and then draw black over the whole 2D texture but it would only appear on the masked (or unmasked?) portions.  But when I try this, the black still appears everywhere on the texture.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: Why don't paint directly on the model in 3Dview when switched into Texture Paint mode?

Comment: Hey, it works!  I was sure I tried that previously, but I must have had the wrong combination of modes set, or something.  Thanks!